# jquery layer slider script is not getting called

Tags: jquery, slider, layer

I am using jquery layer slider in a page section. My html page is a One Page Scroller downloaded from Github. The layer slider in my page section is not working.I have also used an jquery accordion on my page which is working. The one page scroll js and accordion is working but the layer slider js is not getting called.

Below is the js files i have used in my header.

```
<link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js">   </script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Added for LayerSlider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/layerslider.css" type="text/css">
<!-- External libraries: jQuery & GreenSock -->
<script src="assets/js/greensock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/layerslider.transitions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Added for LayerSlider -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
<link href='assets/css/onepage-scroll.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

And below is my javascipt function calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content",
collapsible: true,
active: 'none',
animate: {
        duration: 400
    }      
});
$('#close').click(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({active: false}).click();
    });
</script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        responsiveFallback: 600,
        loop: true
      });

          $("#layerslider").layerSlider({
            pauseOnHover: false,
            responsive: true,
            layersContainer: 1170,
            skinsPath: 'assets/skins/',
            navPrevNext: true
        });
      });
</script>
<script>
        $('#layerslider').layerSlider();({
            pauseOnHover: false,
            responsive: true,
            layersContainer: 1170,
            skinsPath: 'assets/skins/',
            navPrevNext: true
        });
</script>
```

Please help.How do I make my layer slider work.

Comment: make fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you check all the answers ?